# Azure internal load balancer outbound connectivity

Tags: azure, internal

How can virtual machines behind an Azure internal load balancer access internet? Is there an AWS NAT gateway equivalent in Azure?

Comment: By default, Azure VM behind an Azure internal load balancer can access the inter, but you can't access that VM from internet without Public IP address.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

By default, Azure VM behind an Azure internal load balancer, that VM can access the internet, but you can't access it from internet.

If you want to access it, you can create a VM in that VM with a public IP address, use that VM work as jumpbox. Also you can assign a public IP address to that VM, then use that public IP address to access it.

Comment: this answer is not correct. It should not be the accepted

Answer (score 14):

A Virtual Machine that is part of the backend pool of a *Standard* (not Basic) Internal Load Balancer can not make outgoing connections to the Internet.

To make outgoing connections it is necessary to create a second Load Balancer with a public IP with the same backend pool and a dummy rule with a dummy probe. Once the rule is created then it will trigger the creation of an outbound SNAT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#defaultsnat

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me!

Comment: I have two machines that are in an backend pool for an internal load balancer, and so have no outbound access.  I tried to add them to a second LB with a public IP but apparently I can't do that - unfortunately the dashboard does not allow me to select them and only says: "This virtual machine and IP address i....) No amount of widening the window helps.  Thoughts?